# Determine in code if app runs in Expo Go or not (in production build)

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-go

I would like to determine in react native code if the app is running in Expo Go or as a stand-alone iOS/Android app.

I can’t use `__DEV__`, because I would like to be able to determine this also for a production build.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use Expo's `AppOwnership` from `Constants`

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants'

const isRunningInExpoGo = Constants.appOwnership === 'expo'
```

[source](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/constants/#appownership)

Comment: This property appOwnership  only applies to the managed workflow and classic builds; for apps built with EAS Build and in bare workflow, the result is always null

Answer (score 4):

Since classic builds are now deprecated and everyone will start using `EAS Builds`, you will need to use `Constants.ExecutionEnvironment` instead of `appOwnership` which is always `null` in builds done via `EAS`.

So you could use the following to check if in production:

```
ExecutionEnvironment.Standalone ＝== "standalone"
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/constants/#executionenvironment)

Comment: That should be the accepted solution ! 
One question, what is the meaning of "bare" ? Will it be always "standalone" on production mode ?

Comment: So, `bare` is for projects that have "ejected". Which means, they run on all the same expo code, but the developer has access to things like the compiled source code for ios, android, and so on. Just like you would "eject" a normal react app to get access to metro.

You will almost never need bare, unless you want something very specific, given they released `expo-dev-client` which allows you to add custom native libraries via configuration plugins, like `stripe-react-native` or `react-native-track-player`

Comment: Ok thank you, but I have a managed workflow, and in my expo dev client app, when I console.log the Constants value, it show my "bare" for the execution environnement. So that's weird

Comment: @JulienPepe That is correct, because you're using the expo-dev-client.
So, `standalone` is for a production build, `storeClient` is when you develop through the `Expo Go` client, and `bare` is when you develop through your own app (either via ejection, or via the dev-client, as it's basically a "simulator" of bare setup).

Comment: correct check would be:
`import Constants, { ExecutionEnvironment } from 'expo-constants'`
`Constants.executionEnvironment === ExecutionEnvironment.Standalone`

Comment: I've been building the app using `eas build --platform ios` for prod and `eas build --profile development-simulator --platform ios` for dev. 
Unfortunately `Constants.executionEnvironment` returns `bare` for both. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: @Nazar are you running on the bare workflow or managed (eg. Did you eject?) if you did, that is your answer

Comment: @Eduard no, i didn't eject. I'm talking about proper code snippet, because since ExecutionEnvironment is an enum that looks like that 
export enum ExecutionEnvironment {
  Bare = 'bare',
  Standalone = 'standalone',
  StoreClient = 'storeClient'}
your check will always return `true`, because you compare enum value Standalone = 'standalone' with string "standalone".

Comment: @ElDiabolo in case you eject your app, you will get `bare` as correct response, you can find docu here: https://docs.expo.dev/bare/overview/

Comment: @Nazar also, lets no confuse `appOwnership` with `ExecutionEnvironment`, for which `bare` is returned if you are running on expo-dev-client, while `storeClient` is returned if you run directly in Expo Go and standalone when running in the final EAS Build app.

Comment: I am also getting `bare` when using `Constants.executionEnvironment`, prod app built with `eas build --profile production` on expo sdk 49. I was expecting it to be `standalone`, I never ejected my expo app.

Comment: I am also getting `bare` as the value for `Constants.executionEnvironment` in a production app built with `eas build` on Expo SDK 49. The returned value is `storeClient` when running on Expo Go.

Answer (score 4):

in case you are using EAS Builds with TypeScript and since `ExecutionEnvironment` is an enum that looks like that:

```
export enum ExecutionEnvironment { 
Bare = 'bare', Standalone = 'standalone', StoreClient = 'storeClient'}
```

the correct way to determine current environment will be:

```
Constants.executionEnvironment === ExecutionEnvironment.Standalone
```

or for Bare React Native Apps:

```
Constants.executionEnvironment === ExecutionEnvironment.Bare
```